# Sending form data server side

Tags: node.js, express, axios, nodejs-server

I am sending a formdata to an endpoint that requires the following data:

**token_key,
customer_id,
folder_id,
document_id,
file**

but I get an error when sending it, the steps I do are the following:

html file

```
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        if (is_signed) {
          var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL();

          var image = dataURItoBlob(dataUrl);

          var file = new File([image], 'firma.png', {
            type: 'image/png'
          });

          var folder_id = location.search.slice(1).split("&")[0].split("=")[1]
          var document_id = location.search.slice(1).split("&")[1].split("=")[1]

          const formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append('document_id', parseInt(document_id));
          formdata.append('folder_id', parseInt(folder_id));
          formdata.append('file', file)

          axios.post('/send-signature', formdata, {
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
          })
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
            });
}, false)
```

Js file

```
router.post("/send-signature", (req, res) => {
  const url_expa_signature = `${process.env.BASE_URL_EXPA}/upload-documents`


  const document_id = req.body.document_id
  const folder_id = req.body.folder_id
  const file = req.files.file
  const token_key = process.env.TOKEN_KEY
  const customer_id = process.env.CUSTOMER_ID

  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('token_key', token_key);
  formdata.append('customer_id', customer_id);
  formdata.append('folder_id', folder_id);
  formdata.append('document_id', document_id);
  formdata.append('file', file);

  axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: url_expa_signature,
    data: formdata,
  })
})
```

and the following error is

> TypeError: source.on is not a function

any suggestion?

Comment: Post the complete error message. Add a  [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You must use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data package on the backend

Comment: What is the version of Node.js?

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but it was a problem with the endpoint that i consume, i solve it calling to soport and they fix the bug.

Comment: hi!

Where does the reference to `new FormData` come from? is that from 
`const FormData = require("form-data");`
or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the endpoint that i consume, i solve it calling to suport and they fix the bug.